# Retrieving selected item value from a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with a datatext field name country and a datavaluefield named countryid.

I need to get the datavaluefield's value and store it in an sql table "mytable", based on the selectedindexchanged event of the dropdownlist.

Please keep the code in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
requestedValue = dropDownList.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: that will only give me the selected value in the dropdown list....i need the backend value which i have given as the  datavaluefield which is the countryid.

Comment: @Rahul: Do you want a list of all values ?

Comment: what do you mean? the above should return you what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
string value = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
```

*This will return the selected item's text in value, which you can use in your db statements *